# Hamburger Menu on sidepanel

Tags: javascript, html, css

SIDE PANEL CODE:

```
<div class="sidenav" id="sidebar">
    <div class="sideheader">
    <a><img src="Dashboard_dark.svg" class="sidepanel">DashBoard</a>
    </div>
    <div class="sideheader">
    <a href="issues.html" target="_self"><img src="Issues_dark.svg"class="sidepanel">Issues</a>
    </div>
    <div class="sideheader">
    <a href="create.html" target="_self"><img src="Create_dark.svg" class="sidepanel">Create</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()"></a>
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("sidebar");
  if (x.className === "sidenav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "sidenav";
  }
}
</script>
```

CSS Code:

```
    .sidenav {
  margin-top: 59px;
  width: 192.5px;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #1D1F37;
  padding-top: 20px;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid gray;
  align-self:stretch;
  background-color: #1D1F37;

}
.sidenav a {
  padding: 6px 8px 20px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
}
    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .sidenav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .sidenav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .sidenav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .sidenav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .sidenav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

So,I want to create a hamburger menu on the side panel. When screen size comes down to 600px, I want the user to see the hamburger menu instead of the complete side panel. However, my code is not working. The code on which I am working is attached here. Kindly help me out.

Comment: You forgot the close tag </a> for the last tag <a>.

Comment: And I don't see a tag with a `.topnav` class in your html.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov I have updated the code.Now plz help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - Your html source code does not have a tag with class `.topnav`, but you specify this class in media queries. I created a div with this class, making it the main one.

2 - There was no close tag `</a>` for tag `<a>`. This tag has been moved to tag from lassmo `.topnav`.

3 - You specify different media queries with the same breakpoint - **max-width: 600px**. I combined them into one media query.

4 - Add this to your css:

```
.topnav a.icon {
    display: none;
}
```

5 - By default I have hidden the `.sidenav` with the `left: -100%` rule, but after adding the class I add the `left: 0` rule (to display `.sidenav`).

6 - Also, there was confusion with the classes in the media query. You add a `responsive` class for `.topnav`, but you need to add this class for `.sidenav`.

7 - And removed `position: relative` from `.sidenav.responsive`, in the media query.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("sidebar");
    if (x.className === "sidenav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "sidenav";
    }
}
```

```css
.sidenav {
    /*margin-top: 59px;*/
    width: 192.5px;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: -100%;
    background-color: #1d1f37;
    padding-top: 20px;
    align-items: center;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid gray;
    align-self: stretch;
    background-color: #1d1f37;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 6px 8px 20px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
}

.topnav a.icon {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .sidenav a:not(:first-child) {
        display: none;
    }

    .topnav a.icon {
        float: right;
        display: block;
    }

    .sidenav.responsive {
        /*position: relative;*/
        left: 0;
    }

    .sidenav.responsive .icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
    }

    .sidenav.responsive a {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
    <div class="sidenav" id="sidebar">
        <div class="sideheader">
            <a><img src="Dashboard_dark.svg" class="sidepanel" />DashBoard</a>
        </div>
        <div class="sideheader">
            <a href="issues.html" target="_self"><img src="Issues_dark.svg" class="sidepanel" />Issues</a>
        </div>
        <div class="sideheader">
            <a href="create.html" target="_self"><img src="Create_dark.svg" class="sidepanel" />Create</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()"> <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>TOGGLE </a>
</div>
```